# Can I create a custom item for Windows 11 Quick Settings?

Tags: windows-11

I clicked "Add", but there are only a few items and almost none of them were useful for me. Instead, can I create and add a custom item, like toggling Dark theme or something?

[image]
Image from [Digital Citizen](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/windows-11-quick-settings/)

Comment: Should be addressed to https://superuser.com rather than https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko No, I was thinking about creating my own entry by coding some sort of extension, and I was wondering if Windows API allows it.

Comment: There is currently no extension API for this UI.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ah, shoot. Thanks for confirming that. Microsoft should have allowed third-party settings. What a wasted opportunity.

Comment: Third party UI extensions are a huge compatibility nightmare. It means that the UI of Explorer is locked to whatever the extension uses, and Explorer cannot become any more stable than the least stable shell extension.

Comment: @RaymondChen Aren't that problems that can be avoided depending how the extension system is implemented? It does not have to be binary but some sort of simple script, and the script could launch a binary, right?